# How do you capture requirements with declarative acceptance tests?

Tags: cucumber, bdd, calabash, acceptance-testing

**Background**

I am trying to help my team organize for a new mobile app project. We have chosen to follow [BDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development) (see also [BDD definition](http://guide.agilealliance.org/guide/bdd.html)) in order to capture plain English requirements that form a contract between stakeholders and developers for each individual user story.

We use the acceptance tests to document each user story's requirements. Acceptance tests are written before sprint planning. Developers refine and add to the tests during sprint planning.

We define *Acceptance Criteria* as a list of rules (eg: input validation, default values, etc) and *Acceptance Tests* as a list of Cucumber scenarios. We plan on using [Calabash](http://calaba.sh/) for mobile testing.

I feel acceptance criteria/tests are a more agile and therefore better solution to more formal requirements documents.

I feel I have found an effective solution fo, but I would like to understand how others are collecting requirements and writing acceptance tests.

**Problem**

There is a debate in the Cucumber community of [imperative](http://watir.com/2010/12/10/alister-scott-on-cucumber-imperative-or-declarative-that-is-the-question/) vs [declarative](http://mariovisic.github.io/declarative_cucumber/) test steps. I lean toward imperative, because a developer must know what a deliverable user story looks like.

I do not feel UI coupling aka brittle tests is an issue. There are ways to decouple the UI from the test (eg: [page objects](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object)). I also do not feel that having detailed steps make it hard for a non-technical stakeholder to understand (unless they don't know how to use a web browser or mobile device, but that's a separate issue).

I may be misappropriating the term "[Acceptance Test](http://guide.agilealliance.org/guide/acceptance.html)". In my use, an acceptance test is not on the same level of scope as a unit test. I view an acceptance test as a high level [integration test](http://www.typemock.com/unit-tests-integration-tests).

**The Example**

- As a guest
- I want to login
- to access app functionality

*Imperative Test*

- Scenario: Valid login

  - Given I am on the "login" screen
  - When I enter "email@domain.com" in "email"

    - And I enter "password1" in "password"
    - And I tap "login"
  - Then I see "login successful"

*Declarative Test*

- Scenario: Valid login

  - Given I have a valid account
  - Then I can login

These both can cover the same functionality and the latter is shorter, but it does not say if I can login with a username, email or facebook/twitter/google/etc account. It's just not enough to actually code a solution

**The Question**

How do you capture the requirements for a feature with declarative steps?

Comment: Dan North (creator of BDD) has some nice thoughts on the matter: http://dannorth.net/2011/01/31/whose-domain-is-it-anyway/. It helps to keep in mind that a scenario should only address 2 domains: the user of the feature and the developer who will implement it. The scenario should clarify to both domains what is to happen how(eg: "user logs in with email and password", not "user logs in with username and password", etc)

Comment: http://blog.cyrusinnovation.com/2013/04/improve-your-ios-frank-cucumber-acceptance-tests.html says that imperative is appropriate when a stakeholder is concerned with the user experience of a given scenario. It makes sense to aim for brevity via declarative while being explicit with imperative when it's called for.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about project planning. I think it should be migrated to programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I don't think it's off topic as the question is about imperative versus declarative BDD tests, rather than about project planning. Might be worth renaming the question title?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nicely written question!

> How do you capture the requirements for a feature with declarative
>   steps?

The requirements for a feature are recorded in the step definitions.

Hence in your imperative example:

```
When I enter "email@domain.com" in "email"
And I enter "password1" in "password"
And I tap "login"
```

this could be made declarative by re-writing it as:

```
Given I login using valid credentials
```

The steps to navigate to a valid account (i.e. implementing the acceptance criteria which defines what "valid" means) can then be implemented in the step definition for this scenario statement. The same will apply for the opposite scenario i.e.

```
Given I login using invalid credentials
```

Again, the steps to implement this scenario which satisfy the acceptance criteria can be implemented in the underlying step definition.

Taking this declarative approach means that you lose the (imperative) requirements from the feature (i.e. what exact steps need to be performed), making it harder for the business to see *exactly* what these scenarios are doing from just reading the feature file. However, what you gain is that the tests become less brittle, as the specific steps to achieve a task are recorded in the step definition, and this step definition can be shared amongst many features.

At my company we wrestle with the same concerns, and we find that in some cases it's better to use imperative rather than declarative, and vice versa. For example, in your case the steps which make up "Given I have a valid account" may be used in many features, so making it declarative is rational. However if you have a feature where many different string values are inputted, then in that case it's probably best to write them imperatively.

["Horses for courses!"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/horses_for_courses)

It'll be very interesting to see other answers to this question from the SO community.

Comment: I can see some value in defining the acceptance tests imperatively within each user story and then declaratively in the actual cucumber scenarios to make them less brittle. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Thinking about it, we could use the acceptance criteria to list details of what a "valid account" is (eg: email and password, not username and retinal scan). That way allows the scenarios to be more brief while still capturing enough requirements per user story for a developer to completely implement...I'm liking this idea.

Comment: Also, you can add "just enough" detail regarding the acceptance criteria to the scenario title. Hence in your example you could have "Scenario: Login just using retinal scan" and "Scenario: login using email and password".

Comment: that's true, but would that be better as a separate user story (eg: a US for email/pass and a US for facebook login and a US for retinal scanning)?

Comment: Yes, I agree. I apologize for a poor example! What I should've said is "Scenario: login using valid email and invalid password",  "Scenario: login using invalid email and valid password" and  "Scenario: login using a valid email and password".

Comment: Even those scenarios could be covered by "login with valid credentials" and "login with invalid credentials" and then define in the acceptance criteria what "valid" means. If you edit your answer to reflect our comments here, then I'll accept it.

Comment: @Brenden Answer updated. Hopefully I've updated the answer with the crux of our conversation!

Comment: Im glad someone asked this question because I was facing the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I recently visited a shop/online to buy a Washing machine and a Dish washer. All I wanted was to buy one that uses less water and has a quick wash. But the details I encountered were overwhelming; such as RPM, Thickness of inner drum, Total connected load in KW etc.

Imperative style may appear suitable from your simple example above but in reality it makes reading scenarios harder and boring.  You can experience it by reading 10 scenarios from a project in which you are not directly involved at a technical / day-to-day level.

Given that one of the objective of using cucumber is to bring in transparency across the project, in particular the non-technical users, declarative style is much better at getting management actively involved.  I have seen that in my projects.

Here is a fictitious story. Try and implement it in imperative style, come back and read it in couple of days, you will realize that its too boring.

```
Feature: Delivery 
    Free delivery is offered to customers who order two or more items

  Scenario Outline: Calculate postage for delivery
    Given I am signed-in
    When I "<order>" items
    Then postage should be "<postage>"   

    Examples:
    | order | postage |
    | 1     | 0.99    |
    | 2     | 0       |
    | 3     | 0       |
    | 0     | ?       |
```

Another link that you may wish to read [How to implement UI testing without shooting yourself in the foot](http://gojko.net/2010/04/13/how-to-implement-ui-testing-without-shooting-yourself-in-the-foot-2/)

Comment: Nice illustration, but, in this example, the real issue is specifying what it means to be signed in, to order an item and what currency the postage is in as well as what region/nation the postage is for. Like I mentioned in my question, I want to know where you define the requirements for implementation when you use declarative steps. Thanks.