# How to design BDD scenarios for my given application?

Tags: c#, bdd, gherkin

Hi I’m developing a rather simple C# application and wanted to use this possibility to dig into BDD. I think I understood the basic principles, but I’m having trouble applying them to my application.

More specificly I don’t know, how to “convert” my requirements into features/specs and scenarios.

The purpose of the application is to execute different tasks in a specific order defined by depencies between those task, i.e. Task A cannot start before Task B completed successfully.

There are two parts of the application, one is a configuration wizard, to configure the tasks and their dependencies as well as some kind of “playlists” and the other is actual application that runs those playlist.

So the user first configures the tasks and their dependencies and then creates a playlist by defining which tasks he ultimately wants to have executed – the application then takes care of adding additional tasks if necessary due to the dependencies and brings them into the right order to satisfy the dependencies.

I could imagine how to build my scenarios for the configuration wizard, f.e.: (feel free to comment on that as well ;))

```
Given An empty Playlist
And Task A depends on Task B
When The user adds Task A to the list
Then Task B should be added to the list first
And Task A should be added to the list second
```

But for the part that runs those playlists I feel a little lost on how to split the requirement in well definied scenarios. I could think of something like this (happy path):

```
Given A playlist
When The user executes the list
Then The Tasks should be executed in the correct order
```

But that feels a bit too unspecific for me. Which tasks are in the playlist? How are their dependencies defined? And so on... Could anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 1):

What you have looks like a good starting point.

The scenario you have wrote is declarative i.e. you are declaring what you want to happen without specifying exactly how it should happen:

```
Given A valid playlist
When The user executes the list
Then The Tasks should be executed in the correct order
```

Taking this approach means that the specifics regarding how these steps are executed are defined in the step definitions. An advantage to declarative tests is that

- They are easier for the product owner or business analyst to read write (the BA should be writing these anyway!)
- They are less brittle i.e. they are less likely to be impacted by UI changes (for example)

With regards to:

> Which tasks are in the playlist? How are their dependencies defined?
>   And so on...

If you were to ask the business owner about how they would want the application to behave, they are far more likely to describe what they want in a declarative manner (e.g. in the example you gave).

As for an unhappy path example, a product owner might say:

```
Given an invalid playlist
When a user executes the list
Then the application should inform them of the error that occurred
```

Again, it's declarative and the actual detail (e.g. Which tasks are in the playlist, their dependencies) would be implemented in the step definitions.

A couple of good articles regarding declarative testing can be found [here](http://benmabey.com/2008/05/19/imperative-vs-declarative-scenarios-in-user-stories.html) and [here](http://watirmelon.com/2010/12/10/cucumber-imperative-or-declarative-that-is-the-question/). Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19506408/203371).

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question and IMO it really depends on what you want. Sometimes it is enough to specify a scenario like

```
Given A valid playlist
When the user executes the list
Then the tasks should be executed in the correct order
```

This might be enough for a business owner, however, for me this is actually underspecified. Because two questions immediately come up with this scenario: What is a *valid* playlist and what is the *correct* order. It might be fine to have one such general scenario, but I would rather try to give a more concrete or even multiple examples. For example:

```
Given a playlist with tasks A,B,C
  And task A depends on B
 When the user executes the list
 Then the tasks should be played in the order B,A,C
```